# Mat-button-toggle is by default yes in my application

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using mat-button-toggle in my application and the problem is it is in by default YES for me.
How to make it unselected?

```
<div>
  <mat-button-toggle-group name="certRqrd" #certificationReq="ngModel" #group="matButtonToggleGroup" [(ngModel)]="modalData.certificationReq" (change)="certRqrChange()" id="certificationReq" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': ModalForm.submitted && certificationReq.invalid }">
  <mat-button-toggle [value]="true" [disableRipple]="true" >Yes</mat-button-toggle>
  <mat-button-toggle [value]="false" [disableRipple]="true" >No</mat-button-toggle>
 </mat-button-toggle-group>
</div>
```

ts file code

```
   certRqrChange() {
        console.log('this.modalData.certificationReq',this.modalData.certificationReq);
        if (this.modalData.certificationReq === false) {
            this.modalData.certVer = "None";
            this.modalData.certFulFld = true;
        } else {
            this.modalData.certVer = null;
            this.modalData.certFulFld = null;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are asking, but I think it will solve your problem if you initialize the `modalData.certificationReq` to false in your typescript file.

To have a button in "checked" state, you can set it as [checked]="true". See the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/button-toggle/api) for more info.